# Remove nodes in an XML file?

Tags: xml, vb.net

I have xml file and want to remove some nodes:

```
<group>
  <First group>
  </First group>
  <Second group>
    <Name>
    </Name>
    <Name>
    </Name>
    <Name>
    </Name>
  </Second group>
</group>
```

I want to remove nodes `Name`, because later I want to create new nodes.

Here is the code what I have what I have:

```
Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
Dim nodes As XmlNodeList
doc.Load("doc.xml")
nodes = doc.SelectNodes("/group")
Dim node As XmlNode

For Each node In nodes
  node = doc.SelectSingleNode("/group/Second group/Name")
  If node IsNot Nothing Then
    node.ParentNode.RemoveNode(node)
    doc.Save("doc.xml")
  End If
Next
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Part of the problem is the XML is not valid.

[Naming Elements and Attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f0tkwcx%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

**Element names cannot contain spaces.**

Assuming valid XML element names ie: First_group, Second_group, the following code removes all children from Second_group

```
Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
Dim nodes As XmlNodeList
doc.Load("c:\temp\node.xml")
nodes = doc.SelectNodes("/group/Second_group")

For Each node As XmlNode In nodes
    If node IsNot Nothing Then
        node.RemoveAll()
          doc.Save("c:\temp\node.xml")
    End If
Next
```

Or LINQ to XML:

```
Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load("c:\temp\node.xml")
doc.Root.Element("Second_group").Elements("Name").Remove()
doc.Save("c:\temp\node.xml")
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me. I changed `node.RemoveAll() into `node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node)`, because it was leaving node titles Name, but was removing what is inside.

Answer (score 0):

Try RemoveChild instead of RemoveNode.

Comment: I am getting error "/group/Second group/Name" has an invalid token.